# Stored Procedure to display the unprocessed items from total number of items

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to database and trying out some stuff with stored procedure.I am using 3tbales in my stored procedure - Customer, OrderDetails and Order. I am displaying all the unprocessed orders based on the quantity field of orderdetails table.Whenever, the particular order is processed, in my OrderDetail table there is fillInfo field where multiple purchaseOrder number gets inserted from Order table.The data is being displayed but as soon as even 1 quantity is processed then the data related to that particular order disappears.Suppose, if customer orders 10 quantities in 1 order and if I process 2 of them, then that order should be still be displayed in unprocessed orders list because 8 quantities is still remaining to be delivered to customer.

My orderdetail table looks like

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [lineID]
      ,[orderID]
      ,[itemNumber]
      ,[itemDesc]
      ,[qty]
      ,[price]
      ,[priceType]
      ,[contract]
      ,[supplierPartID]
      ,[uom]
      ,[classDomain]
      ,[classValue]
      ,[comments]
      ,[shipping]
      ,[tax]
      ,[reqDeliveryDate]
      ,[fillInfo]
      ,[invoiceID]
      ,[Version]
      ,[productid]
      ,[eta]
      ,[lineOrderID]
  FROM [bfdb].[dbo].[OrderDetails]
```

Here orderid comes from order table where order table looks like

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [orderID]
      ,[customerID]
      ,[billAddressID]
      ,[shipAddressID]
      ,[orderDate]
      ,[employeeID]
      ,[salesTax]
      ,[poNumber]
      ,[dueDate]
      ,[terms]
      ,[shipMethod]
      ,[shippingFee]
      ,[shippingNotes]
      ,[oStatus]
      ,[createDate]
      ,[source]
      ,[comments]
      ,[cardType]
      ,[cardNumber]
      ,[expMonth]
      ,[expYear]
      ,[nameOnCard]
      ,[cvvCode]
      ,[cancelDate]
      ,[total]
      ,[url]
      ,[role]
      ,[consolidationPoint]
      ,[cxmlData]
      ,[authStatus]
      ,[authCode]
      ,[transactionID]
      ,[authDateTime]
      ,[avsResponse]
      ,[cvvResponse]
      ,[Version]
      ,[couponCode]
      ,[discountAmt]
      ,[cageCode]
      ,[awardID]
      ,[versionNumber]
      ,[invoiceEmail]
      ,[trackingEmail]
  FROM [bfdb].[dbo].[Orders]
```

1 orderid can have multiple item number with large quantities for same purchase order

I have attached the snapshot of my stored procedure result and orderdetails table data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIMO4.png)(stored procedure result data)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxGaa.png)(order detail table data)

My stored procedure is

```
SELECT 
    o.orderID, o.orderDate, o.oStatus, e.userName, o.poNumber,
    c.customerName, c.company, o.source, 
    ((SELECT SUM(od.price * od.qty) FROM OrderDetails od WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID) 
     + o.salesTax + o.shippingFee) As Total,
    ((SELECT COUNT(od.orderID) FROM OrderDetails od WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID) 
    - (SELECT COUNT(od.orderID) FROM OrderDetails od WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID AND (fillInfo != '' OR fillInfo != null))) As Filled
FROM 
    Orders o 
JOIN 
    Customers c on o.customerID = c.customerID
JOIN 
    Employees e on o.employeeID = e.employeeID
WHERE 
    (o.employeeID > 0 AND o.oStatus = 'Active' 
     AND (((SELECT COUNT(od.orderID) FROM OrderDetails od WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID) - (SELECT COUNT(od.orderID) FROM OrderDetails od WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID AND (fillInfo != '' OR fillInfo != null))) > 0))
ORDER BY 
    o.orderID
```

There is filled column in stored procedure which shows the total quantities unprocessed . But still I am not able to display orders for the remaining quantities because as soon as even 1 quantity is processed for particular order, the data from unprocessed list goes away. The data in the unprocessed list is displayed from above stored procedure.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the business rules that you are using would help the question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you question is a bit unclear as we do not have any example data and desired result to understand what you are wanging.  In addition you haven't actually asked a question.  Please see this article on how to ask a good question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "not filled" = filledInfo is blank ('') or NULL, right? In SQL 2008 you can use a CTE to get a list of open orders, and then join your query to the CTE:

```
; WITH OpenOrders
AS (
    SELECT  
        OrderID
        , OpenItemCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN NULLIF(fillInfo, '') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        , FilledItemCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN NULLIF(fillInfo, '') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        , TotalItemCount = COUNT(1)
    FROM OrderDetails details
    WHERE NULLIF(fillInfo, '') IS NULL
    GROUP BY OrderID
    )
SELECT o.orderID
    , o.orderDate
    , o.oStatus
    , e.userName
    , o.poNumber
    , c.customerName
    , c.company
    , o.source
    , Total = (
        (SELECT SUM(od.price * od.qty) FROM OrderDetails od WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID) 
        + o.salesTax 
        + o.shippingFee
        )
    , Filled = od.FilledItemCount
FROM Orders o 
    JOIN Customers c 
        ON o.customerID = c.customerID
    JOIN Employees e 
        ON o.employeeID = e.employeeID
    JOIN OpenOrders op
        ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID
WHERE o.employeeID > 0 
    AND o.oStatus = 'Active'
ORDER BY o.orderID
```